# Ordering from a method

Tags: python, django, function, sql-order-by

Hay all, i have a simple model like this

```
def Article(models.Model):
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='article_upvotes')
    downvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='article_downvotes')

    def votes(self):
        return self.upvotes - self.downvotes
```

With the view i can do things like

```
article_votes = article.votes
```

Am i able to order by the votes function? Something like

```
article = Article.objects.order_by('votes')
```

**EDIT**

I'm not near my dev system at the moment, so the syntax might be a little off.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code is wrong, since that method makes no sense.

Comment: "`article_votes = article.votes`" is a function assignment, not a number assignment, and the `votes()` function probably raises an exception - I don't think that subtracting model managers is a valid operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the list after the query returns the results:

```
article_votes = sorted(article.votes, key=lambda a: a.votes())
```

`sorted` takes a list and sorts it.  You can provide a custom function that takes an element and returns the value to use when comparing elements.  `lambda a: a.votes()` is an anonymous function that takes an article and returns the number of votes on the article.

If you are going to retrieve all the articles anyway, there's no downside to this solution.  On the other hand, if you wanted only the top 10 articles by votes, then you're pulling all the articles from the db instead of letting the db do the sort, and only returning the top ten.  Compared to a pure SQL solution, this is retrieving much more data from the database.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you're saying in the second sentence. Also, could you explain the key=lambda a: a.votes() part of your example please. Thanks.

Comment: So its easier to grab all the records then sort, rather than getting SQL do the sorting? Thanks for the explanation on what lambda does, ad the argument it takes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a faster version of what Ned Batchelder suggested - as it does the counting in the database:

```
articles = list(Article.objects.annotate(upvote_num=models.Count('upvotes'), downvote_num=models.Count('downvotes')))
articles.sort(key=lambda a: a.upvotes - a.downvotes)
```

You can also do this completely inside the database:

```
articles = Article.objects.raw("""
    SELECT DISTINCT id from articles_article,
    COUNT(DISTINCT upv) AS num_upvotes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT downv) AS num_downvotes,
    (num_upvotes - num_downvotes) AS score

    INNER JOIN [article_user_upvotes_m2m_table_name] AS upv
    ON upv.article_id = id

    INNER JOIN [article_user_downvotes_m2m_table_name] AS downv
    ON downv.article_id = id

    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY score
""")
```

-- but I'm not sure if the double join is a good idea in your case. Also, I'm not sure if all those DISCTINCTs are needed. It's quite likely that this query can be rewritten in some better way, but I don't have an idea at the moment..

Comment: You're looking for `.extra()`.